# Is a lack anti-matter related to the arrow of time?

Tags: antimatter, time-reversal-symmetry, arrow-of-time

Mathematically speaking, we know that antiparticles can be equivalently thought of as particles travelling backwards in time. We also know there is a distinct lack of anti-particles in the universe even though they should have been created in roughly equal amounts at the big bang.

Could there be a resolution to the anti-matter puzzle that relates to the puzzle of why time only flows in one direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate (though unanswered): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648705

Comment: Yep you are correct, didn't run across that when I was looking before posting. Would really like someone to weigh in however.